# NestJs entity non existing column

Tags: javascript, select, orm, nestjs

In nestjs is it possible to add a non existing column in entity? I need this entry because I have a select with like

```
"attributes": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": 8913,
                    "InnerAttribute": {
                        "value": "201820019"
```

I want to put the value outside of innerAttribute I want my result to look like

```
"attributes": [
                {
                    "AttributeId": 8913,
                    "value": "201820019"
```

My attribute is looking like

```
record.attributes = this.Attributes;
```

and `this.billerAttributes` is `Attributes: Attributes[];`

I was thinking if it is possible to add

```
@Column()
value: number | null;
```

in entity `Attributes` but I always get `error: QueryFailedError: Error: Invalid column name 'value'.`

What is a much better approach for this scenario?

Comment: What is the the query you used..?

Comment: @RomeoTatchemo `.getMany()` to get the result. is there a more best practice approach for this ?